# How to map an observable array in to different data strucutre

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

I have an observable array.

I have a consumer component that looking for data like

```
{
  name: 'name'
  data: [] //data from my observable array
}
```

So how would you map the observable array in to data format like above?

Comment: Can you please elaborate

Comment: `obs.pipe( map( data => ({ name: 'name', data: data})));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that in your service method that is making the actual API call:

**For Rxjs 5.5 or newer:**

```
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

yourMethod() {
  return yourActualObservable.pipe(
    map(data => ({ name: 'name', data }))
  );
}
```

**For Rxjs5 or earlier:**

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

yourMethod() {
  return yourActualObservable.map(data => ({ name: 'name', data }));
}
```

This will transform the data in the form that you're looking for.

Comment: any thoughts on this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53063085/mapping-the-observable-reruns-undefined ?

Comment: @sreginogemoh, let me check